# Populate nested objects what only support kwargs for initialization?

Tags: python, keyword-argument, apache-pulsar

I have some python library with Record class.
Record class accepts data using only `kwargs`.
I populate Records like this and it works ok:

```
class Animal(Record):
    name = String(required=True)


animal = Animal(**{'name': 'joe'})
```

The library also supports nesting Records like this:

```
class Fur(Record):
    color = String(required=True)


class Animal(Record):
    fur = Fur(required=True)
```

However when I try to populate with:

```
animal = Animal(**{'fur': {'color': 'red'}})
```

it fails because the subrecord do not receive `color=red` but receives `{'color': 'red'}` instead.

So I would need a kind of "recursive **" ?

Comment: what's the `Record` definition?

Comment: it is here: https://github.com/apache/pulsar/blob/master/pulsar-client-cpp/python/pulsar/schema/definition.py

Comment: For the record, you know that you could write it like this, right? `animal = Animal(name = 'joe')`

Comment: yes but goal is to populate Record with nested JSON directly

Answer (score 2):

What about simply doing:

```
animal = Animal(fur = Fur(color = 'red'))
```

A little more about kwargs: [What is the purpose and use of **kwargs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769403/what-is-the-purpose-and-use-of-kwargs)

Though, I don't think you can you can do it with a raw dictionary like this. If you take a look at the `__init__` ([here](https://github.com/apache/pulsar/blob/8b0d726cc70d76eff326b90cc77f0a8d362c5c08/pulsar-client-cpp/python/pulsar/schema/definition.py#L59)) of the Record class, you'll see that the kwargs just override the default value of the field and is set with `setattr`. So if you do `animal = Animal(**{'fur': {'color': 'red'}})`, you simply affect the dictionary `{'color': 'red'}` to the field fur.

The only way I can think of would be to override the Record class, for example something like this (*not tested*):

```
class SRecord(Record):
    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        if type(self._fields.get(key, None)) is SRecord:
            value = SRecord(value)
        super(SRecord, self).__setattr__(key, value)
```

Comment: goal is to populate Record with nested JSON directly